# "Could not get screen information" error

Tags: gnome, intel-graphics, gtk, gnome-control-center

I have Ubuntu 13.10 32bit OS. A few days ago I added gnome3 ppa and upgraded to gtk 3.10. I had to fix many gnome bugs. But I couldn't find a solution to this one.

When I try to open display

```
LC_ALL=C gnome-control-center display
```

I get `Could not get screen information` error.

I don't know it's related to it; I can not generate `Xorg.conf`

with

```
sudo Xorg :1 -configure
```

I get

```
 sudo Xorg :1 -configure

  X.Org X Server 1.14.5
  Release Date: 2013-12-12
  X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
  Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-54-generic i686 Ubuntu
  Current Operating System: Linux kenn 3.11.0-19-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 11 18:48:32 UTC 2014 i686
  Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-19-generic root=UUID=c2d1b866-a0fd-4214-b79b-11b2af29da4d ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
  Build Date: 17 December 2013  10:03:52AM
  xorg-server 2:1.14.5-1ubuntu2~saucy1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
  Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
  Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
  (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Wed Apr 23 12:08:43 2014
  setversion 1.4 failed
  List of video drivers:
sis
r128
neomagic
vmware
modesetting
openchrome
trident
dummy
ati
mach64
siliconmotion
mga
radeon
s3
cirrus
vesa
sisusb
qxl
tdfx
intel
nouveau
savage
fbdev
  (++) Using config file: "/home/****/xorg.conf.new"
  (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
  vesa: Ignoring device with a bound kernel driver
  Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
    Configuration failed.
  (EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.
```

Here is my driver info

```
  lspci -nn | grep -i vga 
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) [8086:2a02] (rev 03)
```

I hope you help me fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit. It's a gnome bug or intentional design by gnome developers.

It doesn't communicate with compiz.

So

```
mutter --replace
```

fixed it.

For more info :

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1040062